# When the first city is selected, the first county comes automatically. I want the incoming county to be empty and for the user to select it

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

We have 2 drowboxlists. They are linked together in the database. I want that when City is selected, the town is empty and the user selects the town. When the city is selected in my code that works now, the towns comes automatically.

```
 $('#ikametSehir').on("click", function () {

 var x = document.getElementById("ikametIlce");

 $("#ikametIlce").empty();

 var a = $('#ikametSehir :selected').text();

 $.ajax       
 ({

    type: "GET",
    url: "/Home/getIlce",
           data: { "sehir": $('#ikametSehir :selected').text() },
           success: function (Ilce) {
           var aa = Ilce;
           var uzunluk = Ilce.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < uzunluk; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.text = Ilce[i];
                    x.add(option);
               }
         });
    });
```

Comment: SO you want to create a cascading dropdown lists?  The first one is for city and the second one is for town, When user select a city in the first drop down list, The second drop down list will only show the towns which belong to the city you select, Do you want to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I add first option with ;

> var option = document.createElement("option");
>
> ```
>         option.text = "İlçe Seçiniz";
>
>         x.add(option);
> ```

but problem if user choose "ilçe Seçiniz" I add validation
this ;

> if ('#ikametSehir :selected') {
>
> ```
>             if ('#ikametIlce :selected', "İlçe Seçiniz") {
>
>                 $('#ikametIlce').focus()
>
>                 alert('Lütfen İlçe Seçiniz')
>
>                 return false;
>
>         }
>
>     }
> ```